# Javascript: auto-download file when link "clicked"

Tags: javascript, download

I found a similar question, posted in an older topic, but the answer given there did not work.  I am testing with Mozilla Firefox browser (latest version).

I have an array with imageLinks, and want to auto-trigger a download without user interaction. my code is given below:

```
for (var i=0; i<imageLinks.length; i++) {

if (imageLinks[i]) {

    console.log(imageLinks[i]);
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = imageLinks[i];
    link.download = 'imagefile';
    link.click();
    }
}
```

However, in Forefox the images are opening in new tabs?

Comment: Hmmm.. wait what are you trying to do again? I would assume no browsers let you start a download without user interaction.. because you know safety.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download, but without the user having to click for each of the files.  A button will trigger the download of the gallery files.

Comment: I'm not positive but I think that action can't be automised. Better then to make a zip-file with the whole gallery. God I hope I am right that it can't be automised...

Comment: Technically, doesn't the code above do what the user does?

Comment: yeah I believe so.. and I am positive code can be written that can do it. BUT I hope that the browsers have good protection against it.

Comment: I kind of stumbled upon a solution which is "simulating a mouse click event".  The browser seems to interpret the action differently than the link.click() method.  Please take a look.  It does the trick for my use case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon this snippet on a forum, and it seems to do the trick.  Note however that the browser will still ask the user whether s/he wants the file(s) to be saved, and where.  This query can be accepted as "automatically do this with files of this type", and from then onwards the downloads will be automatically saved to the local drive.

```
function simulateClick() {
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    var a = document.getElementById('myLink');
    a.dispatchEvent(evt);
  }
```

This function can be called on the array with image links, and the user selected images can be saved to the drive.  I am happy with this solution, since it's easier to implement than a ZIP-file with user selected images. The image galleries are small, so the downloads should be initialized rather quick.